# How do I convert this PDO code to MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm quite new to PHP and MySQL and I try to learn how to change a code from PDO to MySQLi. Its about a remember me function with a securitytoken and identifier for a login system that I found in the web.
I would like to learn and understand how I can change the code from PDO to MySQLi. I know in MySQLi there is a statement create and prepare, also I have to bind parameters and execute. But in this case, I don't know how to start anyway.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', '');
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) &&
isset($_COOKIE['securitytoken'])) {
    $identifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'];
    $securitytoken = $_COOKIE['securitytoken'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM securitytokens WHERE identifier = ?");
    $result = $statement->execute(array($identifier));
    $securitytoken_row = $statement->fetch();

    if (sha1($securitytoken) !== $securitytoken_row['securitytoken']) {
        die('Maybe a stolen securitytoken.');
    } else {
        //Token was correct
        //Set an new token
        $neuer_securitytoken = random_string();
        $insert = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE securitytokens SET securitytoken = :securitytoken WHERE identifier = :identifier");
        $insert->execute(array('securitytoken' => sha1($neuer_securitytoken), 'identifier' => $identifier));
        setcookie("identifier", $identifier, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365)); //1 Year valid
        setcookie("securitytoken", $neuer_securitytoken, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365)); //1 Year valid

        //Loggin the user
        $_SESSION['id'] = $securitytoken_row['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to switch from PDO to MySQLi, but it's a personal preference. In any case, look at the documentation for [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). MySQLi does not use named parameters.

Comment: I honestly see no reason anyone would want to switch from PDO to MySQLi. PDO is simpler and has more functionality.

Comment: Yes, this question is pretty funny indeed, people are usually switching from MySQLi to the less restrictive option PDO

Comment: Yes I know - its for learning purposes. Thanks for the links and tips.I think I have now the prepare statement and the bind_param done. But this line I dont know how to handle: $result = $statement->execute(array($identifier)); I cant put something into $statement->execute(); How does this work?

Comment: No, you have to use bind_param. `execute` used in the OOP style does not take any parameters. In the procedural style, it only takes the link https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Answer (score 6):

Don't do it! PDO is simpler and offers more functionality.

If you want to do it just to learn MySQLi then you should keep these things in mind:

1. This is how you open the connection properly:

   ```
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
   $mysqli->set_charset($charset);
   ```
2. There is no bind-in-execute in MySQLi. In fact there is no bind by value at all! You can only bind by reference and you have to specify the type of the value.

   ```
   $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM securitytokens WHERE identifier = ?");
   $statement->bind_param('i', $identifier); // i for integer; s for string. 
   $statement->execute();
   ```
3. MySQLi has no named placeholders, so you need to use positional ones only.

   ```
   $insert = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE securitytokens SET securitytoken = ? WHERE identifier = ?");
   $sha1ResultDueToPassByRef = sha1($neuer_securitytoken);
   $insert->bind_param('si', $sha1ResultDueToPassByRef, $identifier);
   $insert->execute();
   ```
4. The [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) method in MySQLi works totally differently and it returns boolean. To get the same outcome as [PDO's `fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) you would need to [`get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and then use [`fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

   ```
   $securitytoken_row = $statement->get_result()->fetch_array();
   ```

Comment: And using `fetch_array` or `fetch_assoc` with prepared statements only works if you have the MYSQLND driver.

Comment: Wow - this went really fast. I will try to learn this, thanks a lot! And also I will try to find out why shouldnt do it

Comment: @Barmar Very good point, however anyone using PHP 5.4 should have this driver by default and all the versions below PHP 5.4 have been deprecated for years now.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Every step in converting PDO code to mysqli reveals more reasons not to do it.