# How to convert PDO to MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm following [this](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/08/how-to-make-product-filter-in-php-using-ajax.html) tutorial, but my problem is that everything is written for PDO, but the my website is MySQLi.

I've been trying to just search for conversions on www.php.net (for example; `$statement = $db->prepare($query);` = `$statement = $db->mysqli_prepare($query)` ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)))

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
<?php

    $query = "
        SELECT shape FROM inventory
    ";

    $statement = $db->mysqli_prepare($query)
    $statement->mysqli_execute();
    $result = $statement->mysqli_fetch()

    foreach($result as $row) {

?>

        <!-- HTML code here -->

<?php } ?>
```

It's supposed to query the `shape` column from the database but I keep getting this error Fatal error:

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stmt_init() on null in /homepages/7/d410968336/htdocs/Inventory/vendors/php/Filters/Filters.php:68 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/7/d410968336/htdocs/Inventory/vendors/php/Filters/Filters.php on line 68
(in this case line 7 `$statement = $db->mysqli_prepare($query)`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert this PDO code to MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296618/how-do-i-convert-this-pdo-code-to-mysqli)

Comment: I saw this; my problem is that for other [I believe security based] reasons the guys who manage the DB i'm using require I use MySQLi. I don't really have a choice. That answer is a generally good one but wouldn't work in my scenario.

Comment: The names are not `$db->mysqli_prepare`, but `$db->prepare`. My other answer also shows the key differences and what needs to be changed. As for the tutorial you linked, it is pretty bad, as most of them are. Take a look at http://phpdelusions.net which has the best examples of mysqli and PDO available on the internet.

Comment: That website is really useful. I'll start referring to it. Thank a lot!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, first in a simple select query you really don't need the prepared statement. but if you wanna do I think this would help you.

```
$query = "SELECT shape FROM inventory";
  $statement = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
....
}
```

Comment: A closer match is `$db->prepare()` and `$statement->execute()`. This goes back to the crappy old procedural style which is highly error-prone. A missing `i` can lead to hours of frustration.